# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having text dataset which has 15000 records. My data frame name is df1 and text column name is clean. I am trying to find the number of present, past and future tense words in the text column and used below function. Please note I took this function from one of the posts in stake over flow

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag

def find_tense(sentence):
    text = word_tokenize(sentence)
    tagged = pos_tag(text)
    global tense
    tense = {}
    tense["future"] = len([word for word in tagged if word[1] == "MD"])
    tense["present"] = len([word for word in tagged if word[1] in ["VBP", "VBZ","VBG"]])
    tense["past"] = len([word for word in tagged if word[1] in ["VBD", "VBN"]]) 
    return(tense)
```

The above function is working for one record, however, when I tried to pass this to my column in the data frame

```
find_tense(df1['clean'])
```

I am getting below error

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzAQu.png)

Kindly advise.

Comment: I think you need `df1['clean'] = df1['clean'].apply(find_tense)`, can you test?

Comment: @jezrael thanks, let me check. it's running due to size